# Plumbing Rough Leak Test Method

Tags: plumbing, leak, testing, rough-in

Just finished expansion pex rough-in new construction, residential, using a water well as service.

For the purpose of testing I've bypassed the water heater and temporarily bridged, or connected, the hot and cold.

Is it an acceptable method to just pressurize the system by turning on the main shut-off valve?  Assuming if there was a leak I'd eventually see the water move through the system and/or actually leak water.

If this is acceptable what is the minimum amount of time I should leave it pressurized for verification?  If not, what's the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open main valve
- Let pressure stabilize
- Shut main valve
- Wait

(I say 24 hours.)

If the gauge drops, you have a leak. If the gauge drops a tiny amount it could be temperature variation - that will vary up and down if you wait, a leak will always go lower.

For a **minimum** time to wait, [IPC 312.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P5/chapter-3-general-regulations#IPC2018P5_Ch03_Sec312) allows **15 minutes** which seems terribly optimistic to me, but there it is, enshrined in code. Run with it if you like.

I'm a suspicious sort when it comes to things that could leak slowly and make a mess somewhere not terribly visible, so I suggest a longer wait, unless you have the family standing outside unwashed and using a port-a-john.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't plumb in a spot for a pressure gauge but that's easy enough to do.  Is there a specific type of gauge for this purpose?

Comment: 312.1.1 would imply a gauge with 1 PSI markings for testing typical household water pressure ranges. If you want to make your life simpler in the future, put a ball valve leading to a threaded adapter for the gauge on, and leave it in place. Some folks like to use the garden-hose threaded gauges, (whcih you could attach to your laundry hookups, for instance) I think a permanent gauge is (practically speaking) required on a well system. The valve makes changing it when it dies easier.

Comment: [UPC 609.4](https://epubs.iapmo.org/2021/UPC/) uses the same test as the IPC (including the possible exception for PEX). Water is effectively incompressible, so a tiny water leak registers much faster on a gauge than a tiny gas leak. I guess elastic strain in the piping could still buffer the pressure, though.